# Deploying a Bokeh (Python) web app to Heroku via a Flask web-frame

Tags: python, flask, heroku, bokeh

Dear Stack Overflow Members,
Wish you a nice and healthy day.
I am working on a small project in which several Python Bokeh web applications are going to be run/served by a Flask app.
In short, the app in this (https://abouttest.herokuapp.com/about) link is supposed to work under the line in this app (https://tflasktest2.herokuapp.com/). I manage to have these work locally. First; I open a terminal window locally and enter this command:

bokeh serve name_of_my_bokeh_server_file.py --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:5000 ;

second I open another terminal and enter:
python my_flask_file.py

and then simply go to my 127....:5000 page to see the two apps running.

How can I manage this under Heroku? I think I need to update the Procfile but my many trials did not solve the problem. Both files are also running separately on Heroku but I could not manage merging them as I do that locally.
I really appreciate your assistance on this.
Kind Regards.
Tansu Baktıran

Comment: You probably need to embed the Bokeh server as a sub-process of the Flask server. See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.1.1/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py and https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.1.1/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library

Comment: Thank you very much for your time in helping. Yes, I will try this approach. I thought, keeping separate bokeh apps would be a good idea for not to make one file heavier (I am not sure whether this is something to worry about), but yes, I will try merging them with the Flask app. Thank you again. :)